# Wordpress SSL not working

Tags: login, wp-login-form, ssl

I logged out from wordpress site then,

I edited `wp-config.php`

and enabled `SSL`

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

then restarted apache

but on trying to open I got the is

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /wp-login.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Just to confirm, is SSL set up for your domain?

Comment: Well I am doing it on local web server as I am going to self host

Comment: So you do have the SSL set up for your localhost then?

Comment: Yes, I have self signed using OpenSSL, now I have the site opening on HTTPS but in browser it still says `connection not secure` where it is showing `HTTPS` in the address bar.

Comment: In that case, I've updated my answer below. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OP's comment:

> *Yes, I have self signed using OpenSSL, now I have the site opening on HTTPS but in browser it still says connection not secure where it is showing HTTPS in the address bar.*

In that case, it sounds like some links are being called through HTTP while other are being called on HTTPS, giving you mixed content issues. Before you do anything, remove the `FORCE_SSL_` function that you added in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Than, try the following steps using the Search Replace DB tool to ensure everything is pointing to HTTPS:

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder in your **localhost** where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://localhost:8888/wordpress/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. Enter your HTTP URL in the *search for…* field and the HTTPS URL in the *replace with…* field, for example:

   - **Search**: `http://localhost/wordpress`
   - **Replace**: `https://localhost/wordpress`

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.

Also, I'd consider looking into the [Remove HTTP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-http/) which will automatically scan your website and remove both HTTP and HTTPS protocols from your URL links. This way it will ensure that your website doesn't have any mixed-content issues.

Comment: I agree this is a configuration issue but if he's got a 'not found' then he's managed to get the server to start, which probably means it has a certificate, and get past any certificate errors that would throw up.

Comment: I am on LAMP based setup

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Same logic applies to any localhost, you'll need to do some digging on your end since this is becoming out of scope of being WordPress related.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't updated the Site URL and Home settings. There are 2 ways to do this:

1. In phpMyAdmin, go to the wp_options table, and change your "siteurl" and "home" to include the `https://` instead of `http://`.
2. Also open `/wp-config.php`, as the settings are sometimes overridden here. If you don't see lines like this:

   `define('WP_HOME','http://yoursite.com');`

   `define('WP_SITEURL','http://yoursite.com');`

then there is no need to add them. It's just a way of overriding the database values that some hosts use.

It's a good idea to update `.htaccess` to enforce SSL while you're at it.

Comment: Why would this make a difference? It doesn't sound to me like he's getting as far as the actual login PHP.